# jQuery - Validate checked boxes in Each Loop

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes, and I gave each one a class.
The idea is to force a user to check all boxes that apply, and at least one box must be checked.

Here's my logic:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<input type="checkbox" class="chkboxes" name="chkbox1" id="chkbox1"> Text Here<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkboxes" name="chkbox2" id="chkbox2"> Text Here<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="chkboxes" name="chkbox3" id="chkbox3"> Text Here<br>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {

$(".chkboxes").each(function(){

  if( $(this).is(':checked')==true ){ 
   return true;
  }else{
   alert('Please check at least 1 box');
   return false;
  }

});

}//eof validateForm function

</script>
```

When I submit the form, the javascript function is successfully called.
However, it doesn't seem to recognize that any checkboxes are checked.

Can anyone see any errors in my javascript function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function validateForm() {
  var len = $(".chkboxes:checked").length;
  if ( len === 0 )
     alert('Please check at least 1 box');
  }  
  return len > 0;
}
```

Comment: you can simplify that even more. `if (!$('.chkboxes').is(':checked')) alert();`

Comment: Per the jQuery docs "Description: Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments."

Comment: @undefined `is` tests if _any_ element matches.

Comment: Even simpler.  I like it.  No need for looping.